# BigQuery Dataset Wildcards?

Tags: wildcard, google-bigquery

I've used **table** wildcards functions in BigQuery but is it possible to use wildcards to query across multiple **datasets** within a project?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not currently possible. One technical reason is that it would be more difficult to look up the tables involved if the table wildcards crossed datasets.