# How to combine aggregate results from a big number of tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have many tables with following names:

`datasetW01.W01_*`, `datasetW02.W02_*` ~100

How to optimize the following SQL?

```
#standardSQL
WITH result1 AS (
  SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) AS count
  FROM `dataset.W01_*`
  GROUP BY Col1
), result2 AS (
  SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) AS count
  FROM `dataset.W02_*`
  GROUP BY Col1
)
SELECT col1, GREATEST(IFNULL(t1.count, t2.count), IFNULL(t2.count, t1.count)) count
FROM result1 t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN result2 t2
USING (col1)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

For datasetW01.W01_*, datasetW02.W02_*, datasetW03.W03_*, datasetW04.W04_*, datasetW05.W05_*, etc. with just one query?

Comment: How many rows do you have? How long is it taking now?

Comment: my understanding of OP's problem is that it is not about performance but rather about how to write the ONE query that will take care of 100s of datasets (not just 100s of tables - this is taken care by using wildcard) - so no need to repeat resultN expression 100 times.

Comment: with datasets names like these I cannot have wildcards.

Comment: yes, that's were the problem is. there is no wildcard functionality for datasets :o( you might want to submit feature request?

Comment: Rather waiting this to be implemented I regenerated my tables with different name structure

Comment: I think, this is the best way to address this issue :o)

Comment: Currently is not possible to query across multiple datasets using [wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). The workaround is using a different name structure for your tables in order to use wildcards (as you are already doing) or programatically construct your query to access all your datasets. AFAIK, even if a FR can be opened for querying multiple datasets using wildcards, seems that would be difficult to look up the tables involved if the table wildcards [crossed datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455557/10161872).

Comment: One reason to do all this is that separate tables are easier to manage and update. Also search and export is much more efficient if tables are smaller.

Comment: As pointed out previously, you can't wildcard datasets. In this case, as @Mikhail Berlyant mentioned, the best option is open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) for getting this feature in BigQuery.